# iOS: Archive build behaves differently then the Debug Build

Tags: ios, debugging, archive

**Note:** I am working on a Project which is old and I have to provide the support.

**Issue**: there are few textfield where I have to push view controllers instead of opening the keyboard. So I just implemented the following delegate function

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // here I am doing my task
    return false
}
```

It is working perfectly fine, Open the required `ViewController` when I tap the `UITextField` but when I make archive and install the build this piece of code does not open the `ViewController`. Instead it opens the keyboard.

Any Idea?

Comment: define "does not work". It doesn't open the viewController, it doesn't stop the textfield from allowing edits etc? Its hard to say what could be happening just from this snippet. Only difference between debug and archive is compiler optimisations are turned on, which shouldn't be breaking this, and `#if DEBUG {` statements won't work. Maybe you aren't handling the memory of the delegate correctly and with optimisations turned on its getting cleaned up quicker. Need a lot more info to help solve this, and posting more code

Comment: also you could debug it be archiving with a ad hoc cert, using `unified logging` to log messages to the console and read them with the mac console app

Comment: I would debug the app and see if this line of code is being called. I suspect the delegate is not being triggered for some reason. Without seeing the code I can only guess

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin During debug, it is working fine. Ok I will look further into it and post it back.

Comment: I gave you advice previously for how to debug an archive. Follow those instructions (or google for others) and see whats happening when in release mode

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin My ViewController was inherited by BaseViewController and BaseViewController was confirming to protocol UITextFieldDelegate. I just removed it from BaseViewController and added it to ViewController. It started working.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your project contains lines like

```
#if DEBUG
```

or

```
#if RELEASE
```

Looks like the root is here.
Not enough information for other assumptions.

Comment: This seems more appropriate as a comment

Comment: Checked, bud did not found any.